# Wrap references around a table in a two column document in latex

Tags: tables, floats, bibliographies, wrapfigure

I'm writing **a document in two column format.**
On the last page of the document, I have **a table which overrides two-column**. So table occupies entire space in top of the page.
After that I added references using bibliography. References are in two column format. 
My problem is that references are overlapping with the table in the second column.
So my question is how to **wrap references so that remaining references will start after table**?

As shown in the figure, first four references are placed in first column after table but the remaining references, starting from 5(as in the fig.) are mixed with table. 
Any help would be great! Thank you!

[image]

**Code:**

```
\begin{table*}[t]
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \end{tabular}}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{table}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}    
\bibliography{bibname}
```

**Edit:**

Following code is the work-around for my problem. **It is not a solution.**

```
\section{Related Work}

\begin{table*}[t!]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

\end{tabular}
}
\caption{<caption>}
\label{<lable>}
\end{table*}

\section{Conclusion \& Future Work}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}    
\bibliography{<bibname>}
```

**What is my problem?**

I want to place my information like this:

1. section of related work
2. section of conclusion
3. table of experiments conducted(since it is a last page of the document)
4. References

My work-around is

1. section of related work
2. table
3. section of conclusion
4. references

**Table overrides two-column format of the document**. So, table is full page wide. 
**References are starting after the table but in two column format.
So, after the first column of references are over, references start from the top of 2nd column and then overlap with table which is two column wide.**

**How do I wrap my references around table?**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please state which document class you use.

Comment: A full MWE including the document class as well as citation commands and a sample table would be really helpful to investigate your problem. Since your code snippet makes explicit use of non-`biblatex` bibliography commands, I re-tagged your question.

Comment: The posted code would just generate errors you start an environment with `table*` but end it with `table`. from the image it looks like you really use `table`, which is wrong. You should use `table*` (but putting a table in `\resizebox` is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Yup. I realised my mistake. I added end{table*} at the end.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Why it is wrong to put table in \resizebox?

Comment: I resolved the issue by rearranging my table and content. I placed table at the end of previous page and remaining sections and references are now well fitted in last page. This is not a solution but a work around.

Comment: @AmritaPatole you don't justify paragraphs of text by randomly scaling the text to whatever size happens to fit a line, and the same should apply to text that is in tables. It is far better to make it fit by choosing an appropriate design size font from the class (eg `\small` or `\normalsize`) and then choose an appropriate linebreaking within the table columns, so the table fits. It's a bit more work to set up but the result doesn't poke the reader in the eye with a visually jarring squished table.

Comment: You have not provided any example code for the problem that you are asking about so it is very hard to help. Once you fix your example to use `table*` then it will not over-print the second column. So if as you say that is what you have in your real code, what is the actual problem that you are seeking help for?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you so much for your concern about my problem. I completely agree with what you said. I will edit my post with addition of my code and elaborate my problem again. Thank you again!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Please check my edited post once again. Hope it might help you.

Comment: As stated earlier in comments it is simply a markup error: full width tables should use `table*` by using `table` you have specified a single-column table but made a table that is wider than a column.

Comment: Your first code _still_ has a syntax error environment starts `table*` and ends `table` (you would not be posting syntax errors if you posted _complete_ examples) the second code, using `table*`  **is** the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `multicol` package. A MWE is given below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
 aaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbb & ccccccccc & ddddddddddddddd & ffffffffffffffffff \\
 aaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbb & ccccccccc & ddddddddddddddd & ffffffffffffffffff \\ 
 aaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbb & ccccccccc & ddddddddddddddd & ffffffffffffffffff \\
 aaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbb & ccccccccc & ddddddddddddddd & ffffffffffffffffff \\
 aaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbb & ccccccccc & ddddddddddddddd & ffffffffffffffffff \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[6-7]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Where are the references gone to? ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. One reference is going to the external bibliography and the other to the internal.

Comment: I resolved the issue by rearranging my table and content. I placed table at the end of previous page and remaining sections and references are now well fitted in last page. This is not a solution but a work around.